# KVO - observe() changeHandler not called

Tags: swift, key-value-observing

What I want to implement is that the `ViewController` observes the `Model`'s property.
But, the `observe()` method changeHandler is not called.
How do I fix?

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Model.sharedInstance.observe(\.dataSource, options: .new) { (dataSource, change) in
            print("updated! ", dataSource, change) // not called...
        }

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: Model.sharedInstance, selector: #selector(Model.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

Model.swift

```
class Model: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var dataSource = [Dictionary<String, Any>]()

    class var sharedInstance: Model {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance: Model = Model()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    @objc func update() {
        dataSource.append(["key": "value"])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to hold a strong reference to the observation

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var ob:NSKeyValueObservation! /// the key item

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ob = Model.sharedInstance.observe(\.dataSource, options: .new) { (dataSource, change) in
            print("updated! ", dataSource, change) // not called...
        }

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: Model.sharedInstance, selector: #selector(Model.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}


class Model: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var dataSource = [Dictionary<String, Any>]()

    class var sharedInstance: Model {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance: Model = Model()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    @objc func update() {
        dataSource.append(["key": "value"])
    }
}
```

Also model would be simple as this

```
class Model: NSObject {

    @objc dynamic var dataSource = [[String:Any]]()

    static let sharedInstance = Model()

    @objc func update() {
        dataSource.append(["key": "value"])
    }
}
```